Known worst-case to average case reductions?
We know that worst-case hardness of lattice problems implies average case hardness.  Moreover, a paper of Liu and Pass showed that if time-bounded Kolmogorov complexity is hard on average this implies OWFs.
I am wondering if there are any other natural problems that are known to have this property?  Namely, that the existence of secure private-key cryptography can be reduced to some "nice" problem, or that worst case hardness implies average case hardness?

It's worth mentioning that both of the examples you brought up are worst-case to average-case reductions that are specifically not randomized self-reductions (the name for worst-case to average-case reductions where the "source" and "target" problems are essentially the same).


Computational Diffie-Hellman: Given $(g^x, g^y)$ and asked to output $g^{xy}$. You can re-randomize a worst-case instance to $(g^{ax+b},g^{y+c})$ (which are now uniformly random) and call an average-case CDH solver: it returns $g^{(ax+b)(y+c)}=g^{axy+by+acx+bc}$. Since you can easily compute and invert $(g^y)^b,(g^x)^{ac},g^{bc}$, and $a^{-1}\bmod \text{ord}(g)$, this recovers $g^{xy}$.
The RSA problem, in a sense: Given $(N,e,x)$, find $y$ such that $y^e\equiv x\bmod N$, where $e\in\mathbb{Z}_{\varphi(N)}^*$. If the "average" case is defined over the last argument $x$ and a fixed $e$, then given a worst-case problem $(N,e,x)$, you can select a random $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{N}^*$ and then $xr^e\bmod N$ will be uniformly random in $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ (since the $e$th power is a bijection on this set). So you can send $(N,e,xr^e\bmod N)$ to an average-case RSA solver, and it will return $yr\bmod N$. Multiply by $r^{-1}$ to solve the original problem.
Discrete log: Given $(g,h)$ with $h=g^x$ in some group as a worst-case instance, set $h'=hg^z$ where $z$ is uniformly random modulo the order of $g$. This creates a uniformly random element of $\langle g\rangle$; sent $(g,h')$ to an average-case DLOG solver and get $x'$ as a result, where $x'=x+z\bmod \text{ord}(g)$.
Vectorization/Parallelization: Given an abelian group $G$ acting on a set $S$, given $(x\in S,g\star x)$, recover $g$ (vectorization) or given $(x,g\star x,h\star x)$, output $(gh)\star x$. Both of these should have analogies of CDH/DLOG reductions assuming we can sample uniformly random elements of the group.



any other natural problems that are known to have this property? Namely, that the existence of secure private-key cryptography can be reduced to some "nice" problem

You'd probably be interested in Minicrypt Primitives with Algebraic Structure and Applications. The high-level idea is that they take the standard result you mention (OWFs are complete for private-key crypto), and try to generalize it to the public-key setting.
The results are a little technical to communicate succinctly (the situation is "less nice" than the private-key case), but the paper is very readable, and along the lines of what you mention.
